# How to Fix MediaRecorder start failed: -2147483648 in Android 7.1.1

Tags: android, runtimeexception, android-mediarecorder, android-7.1-nougat

I am developing an `Android` app for recording calls.

When I run app in **Android 7.1.1 (Nokia 2)**

`MediaRecorder start failed: -2147483648 RuntimeException` was given.

The Exception has occurred when I start a new call.Complete `Logcat` for this Exception is,

```
E/MediaRecorder: prepare() E
E/MediaRecorder: prepare() new RandomAccessFile E
E/MediaRecorder: prepare() new RandomAccessFile X
E/MediaRecorder: prepare() _setOutputFile(file.getFD() E
E/MediaRecorder: prepare() _setOutputFile(file.getFD() x
E/MediaRecorder: prepare() x
E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648
E/RecordService: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
at com.onbit.mob.cal.RecordService$CallBr.startRecording (RecordService.java:446)
at com.onbit.mob.cal.RecordService$CallBr.onReceive (RecordService.java:377)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1122)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The code snippet related to this Exception is,

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(320000);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
try {
    recorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
try {
    recorder.start();
} catch (Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG , Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
```

Can anyone help me in fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the MediaRecorder start failed: -2147483648 error
was device and OS level dependent. Usually, the recorder
would start 1 time and subsequent starts would fail.
The fix was to add a call to MediaRecorder.release().

```
...
try {
      audioRecorderType_MR.stop();
      audioRecorderType_MR.release();  // <<-- ADD THIS LINE
} catch (Exception e) {
      J42CallerId.printStackTrace(new J42ProgramCheck("J42VM0072E:", e));
}
audioRecorderType_MR = null;
...
```